# Disable or hide button based on date condition in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has a listbox and a subform. The listbox lists names of events, start date and end date. The subform bellow reveals names of participants to the event that is clicked in the listbox. Against each participant's name is a button to delete the participant.

How can I hide or disable the delete button if the start date of the event is past?

I will appreciate your help.

Joseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as you cannot bind a button. So all buttons would be enabled or disabled.

You can use the OnClick event of the button:

```
If Me!StartDate.Value < Date Then
    MsgBox "Cannot delete a participant when start date is passed."
End If
```

Comment: Also, how can I use the expression for the current date like Date() inside the vb code?

Comment: That is Date - like Now and Time. Outside VBA - as in SQL of queries - it is Date(), Now(), and Time().